# How to minimize mat bottom sheet

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to set "minimize" functionality on mat bottom sheet so that It can be minimize and then maximize from the current state, also I want to known that which function is called when a user clicks the area rather than the sheet container area because by default this behavior dismiss the sheet but i want to set the "minimize" functionality on that event and want to dismiss the sheet on some "close button" click evet.

```
   export class BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet {
        constructor(private bottomSheetRef: 
        MatBottomSheetRef<BottomSheetOverviewExampleSheet>) {}

      openLink(event: MouseEvent): void {
         this.bottomSheetRef.dismiss();
         event.preventDefault();
        }
       }
```

I get this code from official site of angular material but i didn't know that when this "openLink" function is called I checked it by writing console function in it but it is never called. so i can't known that on what function is triggered when bottom sheet is closed.

Comment: Just to check, do you need help in opening the bottom sheet?Or do you need help in both opening and closing?

Comment: in closing, because i don't want to actually close it, i want to minimize it.

Comment: Sorry, but isnt 'closing' and 'minimising' the bottom sheet the same thing? Both of them will cause the sheet to  'slide' downwards?

Comment: closing called the ngOnDestroy() method and  minimized window can be open from the rest state, than how both the things are same.

Comment: I would suggest creating a service to keep the state of the bottom sheet component rather than minimising/hiding it. You can then apply the state using that service the next time it is open.

Comment: bro this would not works, i am implementing an audio player in bottom sheet, while minimizing a user can still listens to audio.